# Can you make anonymous classes in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to do this in vb.net (c++ code)

```
struct Banana {
    struct {
        int width;
        int height;
    } Physical;
    std::string name;
};
```

It basically serves to categorize the fields so I can go Banana.Physical.width. Now, I know I could technically do it like this

```
Public Class Banana
    Public name As String
    Public Physical As New PhysicalClass
    Public Class PhysicalClass
        Public width As Integer
        Public height As Integer
    End Class
End Class
```

But I was hoping maybe there is some syntax candy around so I wouldn't have to name the PhysicalClass that I would never use anywhere else anyways.

Comment: [Anonymous Types in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)    `Dim banana = New With {Key .Name = "banana", .Color = "yellow", .Physical = New With {Key .Width = 0.5, .height = 1.25}}`  (mine are metric bananas - the size can be fractional ;)  )

Comment: @Plutonix That's a big banana

Comment: I am not sure Anonymous Types are what the OP really needs/wants though.